# Reading XML Without a webserver

Tags: html, xml

I've got a small experimental project on the go that uses an embedded system to show web pages.

The major draw back is that the embedded system doesn't have any form of server on it (No lovely web server languages allowed).

My current setup for testing any potential winning solution is locally (Just in a document C:/users/me/test/index.html) and then also testing it in wamp.

I've looked into using JS or JQuery but evey resource i've found only ever works when I test it within wamp, which isn't a viable solution for me.
I have a couple of questions:

- Is it even possible to read an XML document without any form of
  server technology?
- If so, could someone post some resources please? I've found a lot of similar topics to mine, but none really cover my predicament.
- If this isn't possible, are there any other technologies I could use to give the same output?

Thanks

Comment: If your system doesn't have a server, it can't serve files. You can't even put the simplest static file server on it? What kind of embedded system is it?

Comment: It currently uses a plugin which converts the documents into .c code which then gets used. I'm not actually heading the project, someone came to me as they needed a way to read / save data without using webserver technologies - php, c# etc. So I though - aha we can use HTML, JS and XML!

Comment: Even if you can't use server-side scripting (i.e. PHP etc), you still need a web server that can serve the files to the user. Since you only need static file serving instead of server-side scripting, you can use an extremely lightweight server (just google "lightweight static web server" or something like that).

Comment: Ahh okay, as I know we are serving files to users we must be using a server (Duh) - little new to embedded systems! I've got a datasheet: http://www.aimagin.com/tgr/tgr12/amgf4connect/doc/HTML/index.html?webpage_configuration.htm Can you see anything on there which states we are able to use a language like PHP? If so oh man this has just made my task a lot easier haha

Comment: Umm, I don't see anything about that, no, but if you have something generating HTML/JS/XML files, I think that would be able to serve them? I don't know, that documentation confused me.

Comment: Yeah same here, it's a little past my knowledge haha. Well everyone else has gone home and I've passed them some code to try, so I'll see by tomorrow if we're able to use php - if not then I'll see about creating my own tag structure in a txt document and then getting javascript to read / write to that. I'm pretty sure THAT is possible aha

Comment: What do you mean "read" a XML document? XML is just text.

Comment: The docs you link to show there is an embedded web server.

Comment: Test done. Trying to use php in a document crashes the piece of code that converts the file into a .C file.

When I mean "read XML file" I mean use JavaScript or jQuery to read the .XML file contents and then output the read file to the current document.